# Kubernetes: Service without defined port

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to confirm whether we can expose service without having  container port in the pod. In the below example, pod don't have container port but service is having port defined:

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: mypod
namespace: ggckad-s8
labels:
 app: mypod
spec:
 volumes:
- name: log-volume
  emptyDir: {}
 containers:
  - name: app
    image: kubegoldenguide/question-29-app
    volumeMounts:
    - name: log-volume
      mountPath: /var/log
```

---

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: mypod-service
namespace: ggckad-s8
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector: 
     app: mypod
   ports: 
   - port: 8000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#pod-v1-core)

> **ContainerPort**
>
> List of ports to expose from the container. Exposing a port here gives
> the system additional information about the network connections a
> container uses, but is ***primarily informational***. ***Not specifying a port
> here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed***. Any port which is
> listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be
> accessible from the network. Cannot be updated

In the service only mandatory is `Port`. If you don't define a `targetPort` it defaults to the `Port`.

So as long as `Port` in service actually refers to the port container is listening on it should work but it's not a recommended practice.

As a best practice I would suggest using names instead of port number as `targetPort` in service. Quoting from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service)

> Port definitions in Pods have names, and you can reference these names
> in the targetPort attribute of a Service. This works even if there is
> a mixture of Pods in the Service using a single configured name, with
> the same network protocol available via different port numbers. ***This
> offers a lot of flexibility for deploying and evolving your Services.
> For example, you can change the port numbers that Pods expose in the
> next version of your backend software, without breaking clients***

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can expose service without having container port in the pod. The default port of container will be exposed for service. List of ports to expose from the container. Exposing a port here gives the system additional information about the network connections a container uses, but is primarily informational. Not specifying a port here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed. Any port which is listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be accessible from the network.

For more info have look at the docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service