# How is it that my k8s service is accessible without explicitly exposing a port?

Tags: kubernetes, port

I am running a http server in k8s, I am able to access the server via it's svc name from another service by making a call to `https://e2e-test-runner.hogwarts.svc.cluster.local` However, I haven't explicitly configured service port. How does this work?

**Does k8s map container port as service port when no service port is present?**

This is my service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: e2e-test-runner
  namespace: hogwarts
spec:
  selector:
    app: e2e-test-runner
```

This is my deployment definition:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: e2e-test-runner
  namespace: hogwarts 
spec:
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 3
      maxUnavailable: 0
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: e2e-test-runner
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: e2e-test-runner
        app.kubernetes.io/name: e2e-test-runner
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/e2e-test-runner:$IMAGE_VERSION
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "250Mi"
              cpu: "100m"
            limits:
              memory: "1Gi"
              cpu: "1000m"
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health_check
              port: 3000
              scheme: "HTTPS"
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health_check
              port: 3000
              scheme: "HTTPS"
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
      # Gives pod 15 seconds to complete any outstanding requests before being force killed
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 15
```

Comment: please take a look at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63526947/9547279)

Comment: already read that, the comment says port is mandatory but even without mentioning any port I am able to access the service, I wonder how that happens.

Comment: How have you been able to create the Service without specifying ports? When I try your service definition I'm getting 
"The Service "e2e-test-runner" is invalid: spec.ports: Required value"

Comment: yes the service was successfull created.

Comment: @LunaLovegood : Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: let me check, for sure it is resolved, let me check how it got and update it here

Comment: @LunaLovegood : Okay check and update here for the greater visibility of the community.